# How to filter in code the rows showing on a datagrid in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using a Lightswitch editable grid screen where a user can add/edit data.  One of the fields is called [isActive] which has values of 0 or 1.

I want to provide a toggle button on the side which allows a user to filter the rows they are looking at based on the value of the [isActive] field.

I'm not sure where to start with the code, i.e. can I change the datasource for the grid, or simply apply a filter directly to the grid?

Any help much appreciated.

Anton

Answer (score 0):

found the answer on the microsoft site:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/10/12/how-do-i-create-custom-search-screens-in-lightswitch-beth-massi.aspx